# Attribute returns null using core data

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, restkit

I have a weird problem with a core data object.

I have this object :

```
2012-12-17 20:20:54.756 test[8581:c07] <NSManagedObject: 0xaa52ef0> (entity: Card; id: 0xaa4ec40 <x-coredata://CF3F8F22-FE94-452E-9BFB-D4216847C8D4/Card/p14> ; data: {
    chlore = 0;
    "continue_filtering" = 1;
    "created_at" = "2012-12-01 09:55:05 +0000";
    customer = "0x7533700 <x-coredata://CF3F8F22-FE94-452E-9BFB-D4216847C8D4/Customer/p1>";
    "cyanuric_acid" = 9;
    date = "2012-12-01 00:00:00 +0000";
    "electricity_day_used" = 67;
    "electricity_night_used" = 67;
    "end_time" = "2012-12-01 10:54:00 +0000";
    "filtering_end" = "2000-01-01 09:54:00 +0000";
    "filtering_start" = "2000-01-01 09:54:00 +0000";
    furniture = 1;
    "furniture_to_get" = "";
    heater = 0;
    id = 39;
    miscellaneous = Zer;
    ph = "7,2";
    "regulation_temperature" = 56;
    "start_time" = "2012-12-01 10:54:00 +0000";
    "treatment_anti_algae" = 5;
    "treatment_auto_stop_filling" = 0;
    "treatment_chlore" = 5;
    "treatment_filling_start" = 0;
    "treatment_floculant" = 0;
    "treatment_hypo_stick" = nil;
    "treatment_hypochlorite" = 5;
    "treatment_pebble" = 5;
    "treatment_ph_less" = 5;
    "treatment_ph_plus" = 5;
    "updated_at" = "2012-12-01 09:55:05 +0000";
    "water_quality" = "Eau bleue limpide";
    "water_used" = 56;
    works =     (
    );
})
```

BUT when I do card.treatment_ph_less it returns null. Do you have any idea why? What can be the origin of this problem?

My field is defined as a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you by any chance attempting to take managed objects that you've created on one thread or queue and use them on another?

Since managed objects aren't thread safe — indeed they're more unsafe than usual in that they're never safe to use away from the thread they were created in.

In practice if an object is a fault when you attempt to access it on a thread/queue other than the one it was created on then it is likely to fail to load its data. That's not something you can rely on, it just empirically seems to be true, at least in some subset of versions of iOS. However is it possible that it's what is happening here?

The solution is to create a managed object context per thread/queue, ensure that insertions and deletions propagate between all contexts and to port objects from one context to another via the object ID — see Apple's [Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) documentation.

Comment: The thing i do not understand is that : When i do card. regulation_temperature , i got "56". But for all "treatment_*" attributes, i got null... If i was in the bad managed object context, everything will be null, right?

Comment: I do not know if it can help, but there are the only fields declared as double...

Comment: If your managed object were on a different thread/queue than the one that the context it belongs to was created on then technically behaviour would be undefined. I have to admit to having limited experience of how Core Data presents things as literals (classically they were all always objects) so I can't really speak empirically as to what undefined behaviour might cause there. Though if you are using the correct queue/thread for object access anyway then I can definitely say that my guess is wrong.